# running matlab script from php

Tags: php, matlab

I'm working on a project which needs to run matlab script  through php.. I have searched for the solution a lot but didnt get any solution..here is code sample..its working fine on command line but not through webbrowser

php code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['filepath'])) {
$filename  = "test1.txt";
$inputDir  = "G:\soft";
$outputDir1 = "C:\output".$filename;
$command = "matlab -sd ".$inputDir." -r\     
phpcreatefile('".$outputDir1."\\".$filename."')";
exec($command); 
echo "The following command was run: ".$command."<br/>";
echo $filename." was created in ".$outputDir1."<br/>";
}
?>

function phpcreatefile(filepath)
% Open the file
%filepath='c:\text1.txt';
fid = fopen(filepath, 'wt');
for i = 1:100
% Create random number
randNumber = [num2str(rand(1)) '\n'];
% Write number to file
fprintf(fid, randNumber);
end
% Close file
fclose(fid);
% Quit MATLAB
quit force
```

Comment: Is your web server windows (IIS)?

Comment: nope... I'm using WAMP server

Comment: Then your paths need to be linux, based on your apache basedir.